# How can I use my written printPoint function in printQuad function?

Tags: c

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
void printPoint(struct Point a)
{
    printf("[%d, %d]\n", a.x, a.y);
}

struct Quad
{
 struct Point Vertices[4];
};

 void printQuad(struct Quad q)
 {
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    printPoint(q.Vertices[i]);
 }
 void printQuadTest()
 {
     struct Quad k;
 
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      scanf("%d %d",&k.Vertices[i].x,&k.Vertices[i].y);
        
      
    printQuad(k);
 }
```

the quad contains 4 points so the output should be like this [ [1, 3] , [6,3] , [6,5], [4,6]] however my function is printing each point by itself : [1, 3] , [6,3] , [6,5], [4,6]
I know that calling the printPoint alone here is wrong but cant find a way to make it work

```
void printQuad(struct Quad q)
     {
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        printPoint(q.Vertices[i]);
     }
```

sorry for my noob question but am really new into structures

Answer (score 1):

Your `printPoint` prints a newline at the end, which causes them to go onto separate lines. You can remove the newline at the end, then print the commas in between in `printQuad`:

```c
void printPoint(struct Point a)
{
    // the \n is gone
    printf("[%d, %d]", a.x, a.y);
}

void printQuad(struct Quad q)
{
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        printPoint(q.Vertices[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

However, this might not be the most elegant, as now `printPoint` doesn't print a newline at the end, which can be weird for users. So, one option is to make a `printPointNoNewline`, then have `printPoint` just call `printPointNoNewline` then print a newline:

```c
void printPointNoNewline(struct Point a)
{
    printf("[%d, %d]", a.x, a.y);
}

void printPoint(struct Point a) {
    printPointNoNewline(a);
    printf("\n");
}

void printQuad(struct Quad q)
{
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        // print without a newline here
        printPointNoNewline(q.Vertices[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Or, you could have a boolean flag (although this is also somewhat awkward to use):

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

void printPoint(struct Point a, bool shouldPrintNewline) {
    printf("[%d, %d]", a.x, a.y);
    if (shouldPrintNewline) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printQuad(struct Quad q)
{
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        // print without a newline here
        printPoint(q.Vertices[i], false);
        if (i < 3) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: ohh I can see that now
thank you very much I really appreciate it